# How do I find matching type of sets and find the total cost ignoring the cost of cheapest set

Tags: python, math, set

I have data in json,

```
---
  1:
    type: train
    name: percy
    cost: 5
  2:
    type: train
    name: Caron
    cost: 5
  3:
    type: train
    name: thameslink
    cost: 5
  4:
    type: car
    name: hyundai
    cost: 20.5
  5:
    type: car
    name: Vrna
    cost: 25
  6:
    type: car
    name: Lancer
    cost: 15
  7:
    type: tractor
    name: Vtec
    cost: 10
  8:
    type: tractor
    name: gmt
    cost: 10
  9:
    type: tractor
    name: Ronan
    cost: 5
```

trying to find out equal sets and then combine the cost of all sets but ignore the cost of cheapest set among all available sets.

so here the cost of trains set is ignored as they are the cheapest and some total of tractor and cars is `85.5`

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: yes, I am updating my opening post

Comment: it would also help if you formatted the json properly so people can post in to their IDE

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it myself:

```
    types = defaultdict(list)
    for datum in cart_items:
        types[datum[u'type']].append(datum[u'cost'])

    sets_cost = []
    for item , costs in types.items():
        sets_cost.append(sum(costs))

    sets_cost.pop(sets_cost.index(min(sets_cost)))
    print sum(sets_cost)
```